# Facebook activity feed not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I cannot get the facebook's activity feed social plugin to work.  I set it up on one website a few weeks ago and it has been working fine.

Last week, I tried to set up another activity feed (from a different FB page) to a different website, and it will not work.  I keep getting this message: "No recent activity to display.
Put some Like buttons on your website to engage your users. Details can be found here."

The like button has already been set up and there is obviously recent activity.

I have tried this on a couple different sites now, and I keep getting the same message.

Is this a facebook problem? Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only things I can think of are to get rid of the facebook plugin code and get it again from the website, making sure the URL is correct. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: We've tried it numerous times. We eliminate all facebook social plugins and start from scratch. We've done this over and over again throughout the last week and a half. The only one that continually does not work is the activity feed plugin.

Comment: same here. Any progress on this issue?